# Time-series Auto-Covariance vs. Stochastic Process Auto-Covariance

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, covariance, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

My background is more on the Stochastic processes side, and I am new to Time series analysis. I would like to ask about estimating a time-series auto-covariance:

$$ \lambda(u):=\frac{1}{T-u}\sum_{t=1}^{T-u}(Y_{t+u}-\bar{Y})(Y_{t}-\bar{Y}) $$

When I think of the covariance of Standard Brownian motion $W(t)$ with itself, i.e. $Cov(W_s,W_t)=min(s,t)$, the way I interpret the covariance is as follows: Since $\mathbb{E}[W_s|W_0]=\mathbb{E}[W_t|W_0]=0$, the Covariance is a measure of how "often" one would "expect" a specific Brownian motion **path** at time $s$ to be on the same side of the x-axis as as the same Brownian motion **path** at time **t**.

It's perhaps easier to think of correlation rather than covariance, since $Corr(W_s,W_t)=\frac{min(s,t)}{\sqrt(s) \sqrt(t)}$: with the correlation, one can see that the closer $s$ and $t$ are together, the closer the Corr should get to 1, as indeed one would expect intuitively.

The main point here is that at each time $s$ and $t$, the Brownian motion will have a distribution of paths: so if I were to "estimate" the covariance from sampling, I'd want to simulate many paths (or observe many paths), and then I would fix $t$ and $s=t-h$ ($h$ can be negative), and I would compute:

$$ \lambda(s,t):=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N(W_{i,t}-\bar{W_i})(W_{i,t-h}-\bar{W_i}) $$

For each Brownian **path** $i$.

With the time-series approach, it seems to be the case that we "generate" just one path (or observe just one path) and then estimate the auto-covariance from just that one path by shifting throught time.

Hopefully I am making my point clear: my question is on the intuitive interpretation of the estimation methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us be strict about what we are discussing. Auto covariance is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance). Let me assume $\bar{Y}_t \equiv 0$ for all $t$, just to make life easier.

It looks like you are missing an implicit assumption in the calculation of the auto covariance. For the observed time series, [stationarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Definition) is implicitly assumed. Otherwise, writing $\lambda(u)$ does not make much sense - it has to depend on $t$!!! Under the assumption of stationarity, the quantity $\lambda(u) = \mathbb{E}[Y_{t+u} Y_t]$ is well defined and does not depend on $t$. Hence, one can estimate it by averaging lags at different time indices $t$ as you have suggested (again, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance#Definition_for_weakly_stationary_process) helps here).

BM (contditioned on $W_0 = 0$) is a completely different story. It is not stationary and cannot be made statinary! Thus, an autocovariance has to be calculated by averaging over different realizations.

Answer (score 0):

Having given this some thought (and since no one has answered the question yet), I offer the following intuitive explanation (but I look forward to more answers and comments here):

**(i) Time-Series**: it would appear that we use time series predominantly for phenomena that only ever offer us "one observation path": whether that be an earthquake, historical rain-falls, or annual milk-consumption in a specific region, etc.

**(ii) Brownian Motion**: it would appear that we use Brownian motion (and other similar stochastic processes) to simulate predominantly processes that can be performed in a lab in a controlled experiment: and therefore we assume that these can be repeated many times with "the same" conditions.

Therefore the auto-covariance and auto-correlation functions have a slightly different interpretation.

In a time-series model, it would appear that the auto-covariance and auto-correlation tell us how "often" the various observations at different points in time lie on the same side of the series "mean" as other, previous observations with a specific lag. The full population in this case is a time-series stretching to infinity over time.

In a Brownian-motion model, as alluded to in my question, the population is the same experiment or phenomena performed infinitely many times under the same conditions. The auto-covariance and auto-correlation then tell us how "often" we would expect the various observations at **specific** points in time to lie on the same side of the "mean" as other observations at other **specific** points in time.

Ps: I do look forward to more comments, answers and general discussion that might appear here. For example, the fascinating thing is that we use both time-series as well as Brownian motion, to simulate stock-prices.

Comment: Any additional comments from the cross-validated community would be most welcome here.

Comment: As Yair Dion said in his answer, the two processes, a standard time series process and a BM process are two very different animals. A nice TS process is generally assumed stationary and the error term can sort of be thought of as the DERIVATIVE of brownian motion. OTOH, the BM process is "accumulating" ( the value of its derivative is being added to its current value during a step ) so it's non-stationary because the mean is generally changing at each step of the process. So, I wouldn't compare the two.